# Low calorie and dairy free "flavoring" for pastry and dumpling fillings

Tags: substitutions

I'm looking to replace a hard cheese and egg based filling in traditional Eastern European savory pastries with a low calorie dairy free alternative.

I've settled on a rich mashed potato, onion and herb base to provide the texture and body of the filling, but have not been able to satisfactorily replicate the cheese taste.

Is there any combination of herbs, spices or vegetables that can be added to the filling so it tastes of cheese?

Please do not suggest soy Cheese, lactose free cheese, or vegan cheese with a vegetable oil base. These are out due to them being too high in calories, and having a strong aftertaste when cooked with onions. Particularly those with a vegetable oil base.

The following question has been read, but the answer were not suitable for this purpose as the author was looking for a "salty-tangy counterpoint", while I'm looking for something milder and smoother: [Link](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54269/non-dairy-substitute-for-cheese-on-baked-potatoes)

Comment: Mashed potato does not seem like an auspicious starting point, from either a taste or a texture perspective. Is there a reason you’re looking to add cheese flavor to mashed potato as your Plan A, rather than using non-dairy cheese? And is it just the lactose you’re trying to avoid (which might still allow for things like Parmesan cheese)?

Comment: @moscafj, I'm more looking for a flavoring rather than a replacement for the body\texture of cheese

Comment: @Sneftel, It's for a filling that's based on egg, so the cheese just gives it flavor.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my questions.

Comment: @Sneftel, Sorry, I've re-worded my question to be more specific. The short answer is that most non-dairy cheese that I can obtain locally are based on coconut oil or similar ingredients. They have a sweet aftertaste when fried and don't meet the low calorie requirement. I'm mostly looking for a flavoring.

Comment: Non-dairy cheddar cheese flavoring is available from various sources (mostly online) where I live. But determining a solution using ingredients that are available to you would be pure guesswork.

Comment: @Sneftel, Are we allowed to recommend individual products on this site?

Comment: @AaarghZombies Yeah, as long as it doesn't look like spamming.

Comment: You say "eastern europe", which presumably means the cheese you're substituting for is tvarog, or similar?

Comment: @FuzzyChef, in this case no. Just a regular mild hard cheese. Hence needing a taste approximately similar to cheddar.

Comment: I see that you have edited. I am not sure how we can help you - you are the one who knows if you can find a place to buy cheese flavoring where you live, or if you can't.

Comment: I'm looking for a flavoring or a substitute, rather than a vegan cheese alternative. Which aren't suitable, if I could please have some suggestions I can find out if they are suitable or available, but the question needs to be reopened first. I've already said twice that the suggested answer wasn't suitable so I don't know why my question has been closed as a duplicate when I've already confirmed that it isn't.

Comment: When your question is restated in the sense that you are not looking for a substitute, but for a flavoring, then I agree that it isn't a duplicate. But it would do you no good to reopen and close immediately as a shopping request. We don't do brand recommendations, and we don't know which shops, in an unknown place, stock the product you need. Even if you were to say "I live in X", the best people could do would be to use a search engine to try to find shops which carry it and deliver (or are situated) there - which you could probably better do yourself, since you know your city best.

Comment: @rumtscho, I originally asked for ingredients that could be used to create a similar taste, such as herbs. Which is a substitution. As things stand, it looks like my question was closed simply so that people could be redirected to a completely different question that had more answers. Even though I specifically clicked on the "No" option to say that it did not answer my question.

Comment: I think I am starting to see where the misunderstanding came from. You cannot substitute flavor, it doesn't work that way. If you want your food to have X flavor, you can either put X in it, or find a product that was engineered to be X-flavored (which is by itself rarely a good match, but at least goes into the right direction). When you asked for substitutions, people assume that you want something whose texture and mouthfeel, and maybe taste (in the sense of the five tastes, not aroma) reminds you of a filling made with real cheese. That's why I think your original question was closed ...

Comment: ... as a duplicate. When you cleared up that you want cheese *flavoring*, it is no longer a substitute question - because there are no substitutes for flavor. You just have to buy it. (There could be a few edge cases - if you had said you wanted to imitate red stinky cheese, maybe somebody would have had an idea how to cultivate the red bacteria on something dairy-free. But that would really have been a case of "put the real thing in your food", because in red stinky cheese, the flavor comes from the bacterial colony and not from the cheese. For standard cheese, the flavor is in the cheese.)

Comment: @rumtscho, I want to substitute one ingredient for another but maintain the same flavor. Like substituting Carib for Chocolate. Or milk for Rice Milk,

Comment: @rumtscho, you know what I want to achieve, but I don't understand how you think. It may be more productive if you simply edit the question to achieve what I want, in a way that's not a duplicate nor out of scope.

Comment: I really don't know how to edit your question. You cannot  "substitute one ingredient for another but maintain the same flavor", that's the opposite of how flavor works - flavor/aroma is the sense that distinguishes one food from another based on the very molecules the food is made out of. You can get a similar mouthfeel and similar visual appearance as another food, and that's what you are getting with carob and rice milk - but you aren't getting the flavor. By default, the substitution you are asking for cannot exist. If you are satisfied with the mouthfeel only, then it is a duplicate.

Comment: nutritional yeast is said to taste "cheesy", it sounds like that's the kind of ingredient you're going for but I'm not sure if it's available where you are or if you will like the taste.

Comment: @Esther, it's sold here as a vegan foodstuff. I can certainly give it a go.

Comment: @rumtscho, You can use use some root vegetables to replace banana. Fig for black bean,  many curry spices can stand in for each other. Pumpkin can be used for some squash. Beats for sugarcane. Replacing ingredients with similar flavored ones is exceedingly common in international cooking where some ingredients aren't available. Or in vegan cooking.

Comment: The pairs you mention are quite random, except for squash and pumpkin, which are varieties of the same plant. I don't doubt that there are some recipes that are generic enough such that you can make these substitutes - but then you will be able to use almost anything from the produce department with similar success. The replacements in your list are not "similar flavored" - I cannot imagine somebody eating a fig and hearing "oh nice, this tastes of black beans". We couldn't take a question for such random, dissimilar substitutes - it would be closed as "opinion based".

Comment: @rumtscho, sweet root vegetables were a standard replacement for Banana in recipes in Europe before bananas became a cheap and available fruit. Both fig and date taste very similar to Chinese black bean paste and are a good substitution in sweet dishes such as pastries. Beats and cane both caramelize the same way. There are dozens of taste substitutions for Asian rice base alcohols. Haven't you ever tried to cook an Indian dish and the recipe tells you how to make taste substitutions for spices or pastes that aren't common in Western countries?